# Ломается JS скрипт

Tags: javascript

Есть JS скрипт. Анимация должна работать нормально. Но, появляются ошибки. Как я понимаю, где-то `canvas` переполняется перекрестными данными, и вываливаются ошибки. Вот скрипт: (превышает количество знаков в теге, залил на **PasteBin**) https://pastebin.com/yW8C3Waf

Вот лог ошибок:

```
nectar-particlesbd20.js?ver=8.0:1200 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
    at Object.drawImageToBackground nectar-particlesbd20.js?ver=8.0:1200:50
    at Object.callDrawImageToBackground nectar-particlesbd20.js?ver=8.0:1130:27
    at Image.bgImage.(anonymous function).onload nectar-particlesbd20.js?ver=8.0:782:23
```

Comment: Слишком много кода. Выберете только тот который напрямую касается проблемы, и добавьте его в вопрос.

Comment: Тут никто не будет тратить своё время на изучение 1436 строчек кода (размещенных, помимо всего прочего, на стороннем ресурсе)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну из текста ошибки понятно, что вы пытаетесь загрузить в канвас ресурс со стороннего домена, при запрещенном `CORS`, чтобы это пофиксить, вам нужно сделать две вещи. Загружая картинку установить ей `img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";` и убедиться, что сервер, где размещена картинка добавляет к ответу заголовок `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. Подробнее, вы можете прочитать об этом здесь [Allowing cross-origin use of images and canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image)